# mysqlbackup mysql enterprise utility issue

Tags: mysql, backup

I recent took a backup using mysqlbackup.

While restoring it, I noticed that the files that were copied into datadir are with `root:root` (user:group) instead of `mysql:mysql`.

Is anything wrong with taking backup or what?....

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a backup, you are right to be concerned with whether it can be restored or not.

To be on the safe side, you must run

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

immediately after the backup so mysql doesn't barf when restoring it.

Otherwise, you may get an OS error concerning file permission during the restoration or mysql startup

```
[root@******* 20130101_000]# perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

Comment: My concern is after a successful restore into datadir.....user:group is root:root so does the privileges with 644 instead of 660 for frm ibd myd files. Is it that usually happens with mysqlbackup or do I need to use any options for it.

Comment: One thing is certain: mysqld will not operate with files whose is not mysql:mysql so run the chown -R mysql:mysql as I specified.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying.....all I was thinking is that I'm not using right commands....

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, but you will have to change the permissions like Rolando suggested. The MySQL Enterprise Backup Documentation indicates [in its "Limitations" section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/bugs.backup.html) that *"upon restore, these files might have different ownership, for example being owned by root rather than mysql"*. Not sure why that's not more clearly described in their documentation about doing a restore - you'd think that just about everyone would run into that problem.